# Add user and user meta after order placed - Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a function that creates a user after purchase hooked into `woocommerce_thankyou`. The user is created, but I'm also trying to set a usermeta field and it seems to be ignored. Here's the function:

```
function wc_register_user_post_purchase( $order_id ) {
    // Get the order data
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    // Get the email address from the order
    $order_email = $order->billing_email;

    // Check to see if there is already a user with the order email
    $acct_username = username_exists( $order_email );
    $acct_email = email_exists( $order_email );

    // If the user doesn't exist, create an account
    if ( $acct_username == false && $acct_email == false ) {
        // Generate a password
        $random_password = wp_generate_password();

        // Create a new user
        $created_user_id = wp_create_user( $order_email, $random_password, $order_email );

        // Set an 'acct_auto_created' custom field so we can check it later
        update_user_meta( $created_user_id, 'acct_auto_created', 'auto_generated_pass' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'wc_register_user_post_purchase', 10, 1 );
```

If I look at the wp_usermeta table in the db for the created user ID, the acct_auto_created field doesn't get set at all.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using add_user_meta instead of update_user_meta

Answer (score 0):

Try to get user_id from $order_id like

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$user_id = $order->user_id;
 if($user_id){
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'acct_auto_created', 'auto_generated_pass' );
  }
```

or

```
 $user_id = wp_insert_user(
array(
    'user_login'    =>  $order_email,
    'user_pass' =>  $random_password,
    'user_email'    =>  $order_email,
)
);

update_user_meta( $user_id, 'acct_auto_created', 'auto_generated_pass' );
```

or

```
if( null == username_exists( $order_email ) ) {

// Generate the password and create the user
$password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );
$user_id = wp_create_user( $order_email, $password, $order_email );

// Set the nickname
wp_update_user(
array(
'ID'          =>    $user_id,
'nickname'    =>    $order_email
)
);

// Set the role
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
$created_user_id = $user->ID;
update_user_meta( $created_user_id, 'acct_auto_created', 'auto_generated_pass' );
}
```